# error while accessing this variable in dojojs

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, aps

this variable is accessible in the onContext function but I want to assign fetched ajax json result to grid's store object. 
grid is the object like gride:{store:"some-Json"} like example

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/when",
    "aps/_View",
    "aps/xhr"
], function(
    declare,
    when,
    _View,
    xhr 
) {
    var page, grid, self, contextId,myResult,samp;
    return declare(_View, {
        init: function() {
             self = this;             
            return ["aps/Grid", {
                        id:                "srv_grid",                      
                        selectionMode:     "multiple",                          
                        columns: [{
                                field: "id",
                                name: "Id"                              
                            }]
                    },

            ];

        },   // End of Init

        onContext: function(context) {  
            this.grid = this.byId("srv_grid");          //working
            xhr.get("/aps/2/resources/" + aps.context.vars.device.aps.id  + "/getresource").
            then(function(data){                
                myResult=data;                    
                        this.grid.params.store=data; //got error here this.grid is undefined
                        this.grid.store=data;        //got error here this.grid is undefined            

                            }
            ),


            this.grid.refresh();


        },
    });     // End of Declare
});         // End of Define
```

`init` is the first method that calls first, then `onContext` method call.. this word is available in that function and `this` variable has this.grid property that this.grid property is not accessible in `xhr.get()`.Properties of this are changed in `xhr.get()`. I want to access all the properties of this inside `xhr.get()` function. Because I want to assign my ajax json result to `this.grid.store` and `this.grid.params.store` property

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
dijit.byId("srv_grid").set("store",data);
```

or

```
self.grid.set("store",data); //self contains reference to the entire widget because in init function, you have assigned 'this' to 'self' variable.
```

'this' always gives you the property or objects in that context. So in your case inside xhr.get, you are able to access everything that available as part of xhr but anything outside of it is not accessible.

Comment: by doing this i got this error  "k.query is not a function "

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [dojo/_base/lang](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/lang.html) `->` [hitch](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch) function , to set the scope in wich your function will be executed .

In your case the `this.grid.params...` referes to the then(xhr) so it'll return an undefined error

So you have to execute you function in the scope of the module as below :

after important `dojo/_base/lang -> lang`

```
onContext: function(context) {  
   this.grid = this.byId("srv_grid");          //working
   xhr.get("/aps/2/resources/" + aps.context.vars.device.aps.id  + "/getresource").
   then(
      lang.hitch(this,function(data){ // bind the function to the actual context (this)               
         myResult=data;                    
         this.grid.params.store=data; //got error here this.grid is undefined
         this.grid.store=data;        //got error here this.grid is undefined            

         this.grid.refresh();
      })
   );
};
```